# Transposing Pairs Excel Formula

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I need some help transposing pairs of columns from horizontal to vertical. Example:

```
A     B
John  Jack
Jeff  Bill
Kyle  Jodie
```

I'd like it to be vertical in a column keep the horizontal pairs:

```
John
Jack
Jeff
Bill
Kyle 
Jodie
```

Let me know if you can help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the same sheet, for example in cell `C1` put this formula:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROUNDUP(ROW()/2,0),IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=0,2,1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

On Google Sheets one alternative is

```
=TRANSPOSE({A1:B1,A2:B2,A3:B3,A4:B4})
```